# Why doesn't my UIView animation work when I put it in a containerView in a different class?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, containers, uianimation

I have done a simple animation on a `UIView` and it works the way I want to. But it stops working when I seperate the code. I have put the `UIView` that should be animated into a `containerView` and that `containerView` is connected to the `animationCode` `class`. The "main" `viewController` has it's seperate `class` as well with buttons that trigger the animation.

From the main `viewController`:

```
bottomTableView.rx.modelSelected(ModeButtons.self)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] value in
        switch value {
            case .One:
                self?.container.animationOne()
            case .Two:
                self?.container.animationTwo()
        }
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And one of the animation functions:

```
func animationOne(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.downarrow?.alpha = 1.0
        self.upArrow?.alpha = 1.0
        self.leftLine?.frame.size.width = 10.0
        self.rightLine?.frame.size.width = 10.0
        self.rightLine?.frame.origin.x = self.animationView.frame.width - self.rightLine!.frame.width
        self.upArrow?.frame = CGRect(x: self.animationView.frame.width - self.rightLine!.frame.width - self.upArrow!.frame.width - 5.0, y: (self.animationView.frame.height - self.upArrow!.frame.height) / 2, width: self.upArrow!.frame.width, height: self.upArrow!.frame.height)
        self.downarrow?.frame = CGRect(x: self.leftLine!.frame.width + 5.0, y: (self.animationView.frame.height - self.upArrow!.frame.height) / 2, width: self.upArrow!.frame.width, height: self.upArrow!.frame.height)
    })
}
```

Here's an image that might explain the setup better: Up to the left is the `containerView` with the `UIView` and below are the `buttons`. Like I previously said. This worked fine when everything is in the same `viewController` and `class`. So why isn't the animation work now? What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: `animationOne` this function is getting called ?

Comment: Yes, it runs through the whole thing, but no animation shows...

Comment: please post more code .... or check outlets .. your image is in container or buttons are ?

Comment: Before each line, print the target. For example, before `self.downarrow?.alpha = 1.0`, put `print(self.downarrow)`. Do that for every line. Run the app and do the animation. What prints?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes put animation code into main queue can solve this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

    }
}
```